# How to get the average between two Timestamps in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, extract, date-arithmetic

I need a little help of yours, please.

The SQL Statement below should be used to get the calculated milliseconds between two timestamps (the difference between e.p_ende and e.p_start).
The calculation is working so far.
And when I use only one filter on the timestamp, it is working, too.

But I need the avg(lz) of the values between two timestamps. If I use both statements, the result is always null.

My first statement looks like this:

```
SELECT AVG(LZ)
     FROM ORGANIZATION.V_UI_LOG_SEND A,
         (SELECT E.P_ID, (EXTRACT(DAY FROM E.P_ENDE)*24*60*60*1000
            +EXTRACT(HOUR FROM E.P_ENDE) *60*60*1000
             +EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM E.P_ENDE) *60*1000
             +EXTRACT(SECOND FROM E.P_ENDE) *1000)
            -(EXTRACT(DAY FROM E.P_START)*24*60*60*1000
             +EXTRACT(HOUR FROM E.P_START)*60*60*1000
             +EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM E.P_START)*60*1000
             +EXTRACT(SECOND FROM E.P_START)*1000)AS LZ
         FROM ORGANIZATION.V_UI_LOG_RECEIVE E) E
         WHERE E.P_ID = A.UI_ID
          AND A.P_START >= TO_DATE('20170327070000', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
          AND A.P_START <= TO_DATE('20170327090000', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS');
```

...and the second with between-clause, like this:

```
`SELECT AVG(ECHTLZ)
     FROM ORGANIZATION.V_UI_LOG_SEND A,
         (SELECT E.P_ID, (EXTRACT(DAY FROM E.P_ENDE)*24*60*60*1000
            +EXTRACT(HOUR FROM E.P_ENDE) *60*60*1000
             +EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM E.P_ENDE) *60*1000
             +EXTRACT(SECOND FROM E.P_ENDE) *1000)
            -(EXTRACT(DAY FROM E.P_START)*24*60*60*1000
             +EXTRACT(HOUR FROM E.P_START)*60*60*1000
             +EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM E.P_START)*60*1000
             +EXTRACT(SECOND FROM E.P_START)*1000)AS ECHTLZ
         FROM ORGANIZATION.V_UI_LOG_RECEIVE E) E
         WHERE E.P_ID = A.UI_ID
          AND A.P_START between TO_DATE('20170327070000', 
             'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
          AND TO_DATE('20170327090000', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS');`
```

Thanks for reading and helping! :)

Edit:

Great thanks to all of you! The solution was much easier. I connected to the wrong database. The table existed over there, is named the same, but has no data... The first statement was working properly, for the whole time. I'm sorry for taking your valueable time!

Comment: What is the data type of `P_START` and `P_ENDE`?

Comment: P_START and P_ENDE are timestamp(6)

Comment: Strange, try `A.P_START between TO_TIMESTAMP('20170327070000', 
             'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
          AND TO_TIMESTAMP('20170327090000', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')` or `A.P_START between TIMESTAMP '2017-03-27 07:00:00' AND TIMESTAMP '2017-03-27 09:00:00'`

Comment: I'm sorry and very thankful for your help! But this is giving also the null result (in both cases).

Comment: Are there any NULL values for `P_ENDE`? In such case `EXTRACT(... FROM E.P_ENDE)` also returns NULL and entire calculation yields in NULL.

Comment: Have you just looked for data behind the query ignoring the calculation involved? First satisfy yourself that there is data to match the give criteria.

Comment: That was the problem. My connection ran against the wrong database -.-"

THANK YOU ALL, very very much!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use below mentioned code

```
SELECT AVG(ECHTLZ)
FROM ORGANIZATION.V_UI_LOG_SEND A,
  (SELECT E.P_ID,
    (E.P_ENDE -E.P_START)*60*24*60 AS ECHTLZ
  FROM ORGANIZATION.V_UI_LOG_RECEIVE E
  ) E
WHERE E.P_ID = A.UI_ID
AND A.P_START BETWEEN TO_DATE('20170327070000', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') AND TO_DATE('20170327090000', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
```

This will give average in seconds

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But the result is Error 00932. 00000 -"inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Comment: This will not work, as `P_START` and `P_ENDE` are `TIMESTAMP` data type. The result will be an `INTERVAL` data type not a `NUMBER` where you cannot make multiply.

Comment: Thanks for your knowledge, Mr. Domscheit!

Comment: xTex , as you have timestamp in the p_start and p_end , Please convert p_start and p_Ends to date format, using to_date() function and it will work fine

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't get it. When I use `SELECT AVG(ECHTLZ)
FROM ORGANIZATION.V_UI_LOG_SEND A,
  (SELECT E.P_ID,
    (to_date(E.P_ENDE,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') - to_date(E.P_START, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'))*60*24*60 AS ECHTLZ
  FROM ORGANIZATION.V_UI_LOG_RECEIVE E
  ) E
WHERE E.P_ID = A.UI_ID;` I get the following error: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected.  Maybe as helpful information, my timestamps are stored in the following format: `14.02.17 12:47:16,050000000`

Comment: try to use to_date(p_start,'dd-mon-yy hh:mi:ss AM') or  to_date(p_start, 'dd-mon-yy hh24:mi:ss')

Comment: Try `CAST(E.P_ENDE AS DATE)` instead of `TO_DATE(...)`. However, I don't think it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you! The problem wasn't the statement, more the wrong db connection. -.-"

Answer (score 0):

If the columns are timestamps then use TO_TIMESTAMP() *instead of to_date()*

What does this query produce?

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.UI_ID
FROM ORGANIZATION.V_UI_LOG_SEND A
WHERE A.P_START >= TO_TIMESTAMP('20170327070000', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
AND A.P_START <= TO_TIMESTAMP('20170327090000', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS');
```

If there are no rows to meet that timestamp range then the overall query will be NULL

If there are rows from that query, do they match to rows in the other view?

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.UI_ID
FROM ORGANIZATION.V_UI_LOG_SEND A
INNER JOIN ORGANIZATION.V_UI_LOG_RECEIVE E ON E.P_ID = A.UI_ID
WHERE A.P_START >= TO_TIMESTAMP('20170327070000', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
AND A.P_START <= TO_TIMESTAMP('20170327090000', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS');
```

If there are rows from that query then your average calculation should also work, **although you do have to cater for NULLs.** (+ EDIT)

```
SELECT E.P_END, E.P_START
FROM ORGANIZATION.V_UI_LOG_SEND A
INNER JOIN ORGANIZATION.V_UI_LOG_RECEIVE E ON E.P_ID = A.UI_ID
WHERE A.P_START >= TO_TIMESTAMP('20170327070000', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
AND A.P_START <= TO_TIMESTAMP('20170327090000', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
AND (E.P_END IS NOT NULL AND E.P_START IS NOT NULL);
```

If there is data returned by this then your average calculation should also work.

Comment: Thank you for your help! The solution was much easier... I used the wrong database connection. -.-" 


`AND A.P_START >= TO_DATE(:QUERYDATUM1, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
 AND A.P_START <= TO_DATE(:QUERYDATUM2, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
`

Was working the whole time.

Comment: It's easy to assume the complex bits are the items that fail, going back to basics often helps us re-focus... Please use TO_TIMESTAMP **if that column is a timestamp**